# When using magento 2.4, what is the location of debug logs for guzzlehttp client?

Tags: php, http, magento, guzzle

I have tried checking debug logs from the system and tried to find guzzle path in /var/log. Couldn't get in any of these location. Please help

return new Client([
'handler' => new \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack(new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler()),
'debug' => true,
'base_uri' => 'https://xxx.yyy.co',
'timeout'  => 2.0
]);

Expected logs in /var/log/ -> guzzle directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.